# Strange behavior of hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and I have getting some strange behavior from it, below is the scenario.

My java files are

UserDetails.java

```
package org.javabrains.faisal.dto;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String userName;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="USER_VEHICLE",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="VEHICLE_ID"))
    private Collection<Vehicle> vehicle = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Collection<Vehicle> getVehicle() {
        return vehicle;
    }

    public void setVehicle(Collection<Vehicle> vehicle) {
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
    }

}
```

Vehicle.java

```
package org.javabrains.faisal.dto;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name="VEHICLE")
public class Vehicle {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="VEHICLE_ID")
    private int vehicleId;

    @Column(name="VEHICLE_NAME")
    private String vehicleName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="vehicle")
    private Collection<UserDetails> userList=new ArrayList<UserDetails>();


    public Collection<UserDetails> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    public void setUserList(Collection<UserDetails> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    public int getVehicleId() {
        return vehicleId;
    }

    public void setVehicleId(int vehicleId) {
        this.vehicleId = vehicleId;
    }

    public String getVehicleName() {
        return vehicleName;
    }

    public void setVehicleName(String vehicleName) {
        this.vehicleName = vehicleName;
    }


}
```

HibernateTest.java

```
package org.javabrain.faisal.hibernate;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.javabrains.faisal.dto.UserDetails;
import org.javabrains.faisal.dto.Vehicle;
public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        UserDetails user2 = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserName("Faisal");
        user2.setUserName("Raza");



        Vehicle vehicle=new Vehicle();
        Vehicle vehicle2=new Vehicle();
        Vehicle vehicle3=new Vehicle();

        vehicle.setVehicleName("Bullet ThunderBird");
        vehicle2.setVehicleName("yamaha");
        vehicle3.setVehicleName("bullet");


        //Didirectional relationship
        user.getVehicle().add(vehicle);
        vehicle.getUserList().add(user);

        user.getVehicle().add(vehicle2);
        vehicle2.getUserList().add(user);

        user2.getVehicle().add(vehicle3);
        vehicle3.getUserList().add(user2);

        // sessionFactory one object per application
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
                .buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        session.beginTransaction(); 
        session.save(user);
        session.save(user2);

        session.save(vehicle);
        session.save(vehicle2);
        session.save(vehicle3);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();



    }

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  ~ Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
  ~
  ~ License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later.
  ~ See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.
  -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <!-- 3306 is default port number for mysql -->
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- re-create the database every time -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Name the annotated entity class 
        Here we have declared the class which have entities

        if you define a new entity class; an entry goes here below
        -->
        <mapping class="org.javabrains.faisal.dto.UserDetails"/>
        <mapping class="org.javabrains.faisal.dto.Vehicle"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

I added below code in userDetails.java

```
@JoinTable(name="USER_VEHICLE",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="VEHICLE_ID"))
```

and run the application:-

Full stack trace while there were tables defined from previous application run(the one without above line) in the database..

```
Feb 26, 2016 12:58:13 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
Feb 26, 2016 12:58:13 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 26, 2016 12:58:13 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Feb 26, 2016 12:58:13 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Feb 26, 2016 12:58:13 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Feb 26, 2016 12:58:13 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb]
Feb 26, 2016 12:58:13 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Feb 26, 2016 12:58:13 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Feb 26, 2016 12:58:13 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Feb 26, 2016 12:58:14 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Hibernate: alter table USER_VEHICLE drop foreign key FK48dbrk0k7004g3jff5xftyrxx
Hibernate: alter table USER_VEHICLE drop foreign key FKay5vn6ovfwhmoi2w1wrxxry0
Hibernate: drop table if exists hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: drop table if exists USER_DETAILS
Feb 26, 2016 12:58:15 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Unable to execute command [drop table if exists USER_DETAILS]
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Unable to execute command [drop table if exists USER_DETAILS]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.javabrain.faisal.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:40)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint 
fails
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2499)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:844)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:51)
    ... 13 more

Hibernate: drop table if exists USER_VEHICLE
Hibernate: drop table if exists VEHICLE
Feb 26, 2016 12:58:16 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Unable to execute command [drop table if exists VEHICLE]
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Unable to execute command [drop table if exists VEHICLE]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.javabrain.faisal.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:40)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint 
fails
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2499)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:844)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:51)
    ... 13 more

Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint)
Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: create table USER_DETAILS (USER_ID integer not null, USER_NAME varchar(255), primary key (USER_ID))
Feb 26, 2016 12:58:16 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Unable to execute command [create table USER_DETAILS (USER_ID integer not null, USER_
NAME varchar(255), primary key (USER_ID))]
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Unable to execute command [create table USER_DETAILS (USER_ID integer not null, USER_NAME va
rchar(255), primary key (USER_ID))]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:408)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.javabrain.faisal.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:40)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'user_details' already exists
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2499)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:844)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:51)
    ... 13 more

Hibernate: create table USER_VEHICLE (USER_ID integer not null, VEHICLE_ID integer not null)
Hibernate: create table VEHICLE (VEHICLE_ID integer not null, VEHICLE_NAME varchar(255), primary key (VEHICLE_ID))
Feb 26, 2016 12:58:16 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Unable to execute command [create table VEHICLE (VEHICLE_ID integer not null, VEHICLE
_NAME varchar(255), primary key (VEHICLE_ID))]
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Unable to execute command [create table VEHICLE (VEHICLE_ID integer not null, VEHICLE_NAME v
archar(255), primary key (VEHICLE_ID))]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:408)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.javabrain.faisal.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:40)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'vehicle' already exists
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2499)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:844)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:51)
    ... 13 more
```

Re-running the application again with (no code changes) and getting no errors in the stacktrace

```
Feb 26, 2016 1:01:22 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
Feb 26, 2016 1:01:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 26, 2016 1:01:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Feb 26, 2016 1:01:22 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Feb 26, 2016 1:01:22 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Feb 26, 2016 1:01:22 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb]
Feb 26, 2016 1:01:22 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Feb 26, 2016 1:01:22 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Feb 26, 2016 1:01:22 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Feb 26, 2016 1:01:23 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Hibernate: alter table USER_VEHICLE drop foreign key FK48dbrk0k7004g3jff5xftyrxx
Hibernate: alter table USER_VEHICLE drop foreign key FKay5vn6ovfwhmoi2w1wrxxry0
Hibernate: drop table if exists hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: drop table if exists USER_DETAILS
Hibernate: drop table if exists USER_VEHICLE
Hibernate: drop table if exists VEHICLE
Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint)
Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
Hibernate: create table USER_DETAILS (USER_ID integer not null, USER_NAME varchar(255), primary key (USER_ID))
Hibernate: create table USER_VEHICLE (USER_ID integer not null, VEHICLE_ID integer not null)
Hibernate: create table VEHICLE (VEHICLE_ID integer not null, VEHICLE_NAME varchar(255), primary key (VEHICLE_ID))
Hibernate: alter table USER_VEHICLE add constraint FK48dbrk0k7004g3jff5xftyrxx foreign key (VEHICLE_ID) references VEHICLE (VEHICLE_ID)
Hibernate: alter table USER_VEHICLE add constraint FKay5vn6ovfwhmoi2w1wrxxry0 foreign key (USER_ID) references USER_DETAILS (USER_ID)
Feb 26, 2016 1:01:28 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@1ad9bb2'
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into USER_DETAILS (USER_NAME, USER_ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into USER_DETAILS (USER_NAME, USER_ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into VEHICLE (VEHICLE_NAME, VEHICLE_ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into VEHICLE (VEHICLE_NAME, VEHICLE_ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into VEHICLE (VEHICLE_NAME, VEHICLE_ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into USER_VEHICLE (USER_ID, VEHICLE_ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into USER_VEHICLE (USER_ID, VEHICLE_ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into USER_VEHICLE (USER_ID, VEHICLE_ID) values (?, ?)
```

So my question is why does the application didn't  run successfully in the first run and why did it run successfully in second run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
        @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name="USER_VEHICLE",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="VEHICLE_ID"))
        private Collection<Vehicle> vehicle = new ArrayList<>();
```

also remove or modify this property in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Comment: By using update , I got no errors, but I have to re-create the database in every run of the application

Comment: Hibernate: alter table USER_VEHICLE drop foreign key FK48dbrk0k7004g3jff5xftyrxx
Hibernate: alter table USER_VEHICLE drop foreign key FKay5vn6ovfwhmoi2w1wrxxry0
 getting errors in above two lines


Hibernate: drop table if exists hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: drop table if exists USER_DETAILS
Hibernate: drop table if exists USER_VEHICLE
Hibernate: drop table if exists VEHICLE

Comment: its mappedBy in vehicle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104605/discussion-between-md-faisal-and-tipu-sultan).

Answer (score 1):

When you use

> `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`

Hibernate first tries to drop the tables that you're using and then recreates them every time.

So when you're running your application for the first time, since the tables doesn't exist in the database, you're facing the error. When you run your program from next time, you'll not see the above error, as the tables exist and hibernate will be able to drop them successfully.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the error that you have is because of the order you are creating/deleting your tables:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint 
>   fails

This is because you are having a FK that you are not deleting when you run this:

```
drop table if exists USER_DETAILS
```

you need to change your relation to allow Cascade for deleting child objects.

this is an example: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-cascade

Comment: added line 
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 

and found that it still gives an error for the first time

Comment: I am not deleting it manually, I just run the java application

Comment: try to change this:  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
 to:  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104604/discussion-between-md-faisal-and-mvlaicevich).

Answer (score 0):

I check your mapping — everything works fine, using the same Hibernate 5.1 version. Looks like a problem is not with mapping. So what you can try to do

1. I use old MySQL version (4.1). If you use MySQL 5, try to set

   `<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>`
2. Check MySQL driver. I use `mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar`.
3. Drop all database (not tables, but all database) using MySQL.

SQL commands from log of my try (you can execute it using MySQL)

```
alter table USER_VEHICLE 
    drop 
    foreign key FK48dbrk0k7004g3jff5xftyrxx

alter table USER_VEHICLE 
    drop 
    foreign key FKay5vn6ovfwhmoi2w1wrxxry0

drop table if exists USER_DETAILS

drop table if exists USER_VEHICLE

drop table if exists VEHICLE

create table USER_DETAILS (
    USER_ID integer not null,
    USER_NAME varchar(255),
    primary key (USER_ID)
)

create table USER_VEHICLE (
    USER_ID integer not null,
    VEHICLE_ID integer not null
)

create table VEHICLE (
    VEHICLE_ID integer not null,
    VEHICLE_NAME varchar(255),
    primary key (VEHICLE_ID)
)

alter table USER_VEHICLE 
    add constraint FK48dbrk0k7004g3jff5xftyrxx 
    foreign key (VEHICLE_ID) 
    references VEHICLE (VEHICLE_ID)

alter table USER_VEHICLE 
    add constraint FKay5vn6ovfwhmoi2w1wrxxry0 
    foreign key (USER_ID) 
    references USER_DETAILS (USER_ID)
```